# Excel Chart Colour

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Sometimes in Excel I create a chart, set the column/line/background colours to specific colours/gradients. Then some time passes and I go back to the chart and although the colours are showing correct under Fill instead of showing the Solid Fill or Gradient Fill option ticked and the colour, it instead has Automatic selected and the colour is not shown, so I have no way of seeing which colour I chose.

Is there a way to have the colour shown, or have the colour/gradient of a chart element extracted using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

As per my first impression, you should be able to see the colour just by clicking on the Series, but as this does not seems to be the case you can try a different approach
extracting the colour you choose using VBA as soon as you finish your chart and maybe save them in a support sheet. I have for instance cases where the colours or other formats are lost just by closing and reopening the file. There is questin at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825269/vba-extracting-the-rgb-value-of-lines-in-a-chart-with-default-colors) that could help you with this challenge. If this one does not work, please let me know so we can figure another way out.